# Iterate over DataFrame Date Groups in order, with reference to previous group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, iteration

I have a MultiIndex (`Name`, `Date`) DataFrame `df` that I need to process iteratively by `Date` in order to assign a value that is based on both the current and previous Date's Group.

AFAIK the best way to process DataFrame Groups is by `.apply` – e.g., `df.groupby('Date').apply(ifunc)`.

But how can I best do this when `ifunc` needs to reference the values from the previous Date Group *after that previous Group has been processed by `ifunc`*?

Here is an example of such an `ifunc` to operate on `df` with columns `['Dollars', 'Weight', 'Return', 'HaveMax']`:

```py
# (This might not be great python; coding improvements welcome!)
# Lambda to add "AddDollars" to Names that don't already "HaveMax" "MaxDollars"
def ifunc(group, previous):  # Arguments are df groups by Date
    group['HaveMax'] = previous['HaveMax']
    # Each Name's Dollars changed from the previous Date
    avgWeights = group['Weight'].mean()
    group['Dollars'] = group['Weight'] * previous['Dollars'] * group['Return'] / avgWeights
    # Now add "AddDollars" to Names that were under
    group.loc[group['HaveMax'] == False, 'Dollars'] = group[group['HaveMax'] == False]['Dollars'] + AddDollars
    # Update HaveMax for any Names that reached MaxDollars on this Date
    group.loc[group['HaveMax'] == False, 'HaveMax'] = group[group['HaveMax'] == False]['Dollars'] >= MaxDollars
    return group
```

---

Sample data:

```py
AddDollars = 1.0
MaxDollars = 10.0
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[('A', '20210101', 9.0, 1.0, 0, False),
                        ('B', '20210101', 5.0, 1.0, 0, False),
                        ('C', '20210101', 5.0, 1.0, 0, True),
                        ('A', '20210102', 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, False),
                        ('B', '20210102', 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, False),
                        ('C', '20210102', 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, False)],
                  columns=('Name', 'Date', 'Dollars', 'Weight', 'Return', 'HaveMax')).set_index(['Name', 'Date'])
```

Desired output:

```
               Dollars  Weight  Return  HaveMax
Name Date                                      
A    20210101      9.0     1.0    0.0    False
B    20210101      5.0     1.0    0.0    False
C    20210101      5.0     1.0    0.0     True
A    20210102     10.0     1.0    1.0     True
B    20210102      6.0     1.0    1.0    False
C    20210102      5.0     1.0    1.0     True
```

Comment: It's likely that you can play around with lazy groupby. You should definitely add some sample data and expected output.

Comment: @QuangHoang I just added sample data and expected output.  What does "lazy groupby" refer to?  Is DataFrame.GroupBy guaranteed to .apply in index order?  Or should I not even be using .apply because that might be parallelized and calculation order is not guaranteed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through the groups using `groupby`.

```py
AddDollars = 1.0
MaxDollars = 10.0
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[('A', '20210101', 9.0, 1.0, 0, False),
                        ('B', '20210101', 5.0, 1.0, 0, False),
                        ('C', '20210101', 5.0, 1.0, 0, True),
                        ('A', '20210102', 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, False),
                        ('B', '20210102', 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, False),
                        ('C', '20210102', 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, False)],
                  columns=('Name', 'Date', 'Dollars', 'Weight', 'Return', 'HaveMax')).set_index(['Name', 'Date'])

dft = df.groupby(df.index.get_level_values('Date'))
groupings = list(dft.groups.keys())
previous = dft.get_group(groupings[0])
for i, gkey in enumerate(groupings[1:], 1):
    group = dft.get_group(gkey)
    group['HaveMax'] = previous['HaveMax'].values
    avgWeights = group['Weight'].mean()
    group['Dollars'] = group['Weight'].values * previous['Dollars'].values * group['Return'].values / avgWeights
    group.loc[group['HaveMax'] == False, 'Dollars'] = group[group['HaveMax'] == False]['Dollars'] + AddDollars
    group.loc[group['HaveMax'] == False, 'HaveMax'] = group[group['HaveMax'] == False]['Dollars'] >= MaxDollars
    # Assign the calculated values back to the DataFrame:
    df.loc[group.index] = group
    # Prepare for next iteration:
    previous = group
```

Comment: Excellent.  I was able to rework your draft into the loop and assign form in the current edit.