# Set values in pandas DataFrame group

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

How can I assign values in a DataFrame group without triggering `SettingWithCopyWarning`?

I want to be able to get a reference to a DataFrame group and then be able to access and set column values in that group.

I can't use `.apply` or `.transform` because I will [need to reference the preceding group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66177256/2662901) while setting values.

So, for example with:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[('A', '20210101', 9.0, False),
                        ('B', '20210101', 5.0, False),
                        ('C', '20210101', 5.0, True),
                        ('A', '20210102', 0.0, False),
                        ('B', '20210102', 0.0, False),
                        ('C', '20210102', 0.0, False)],
                  columns=('Name', 'Date', 'Dollars', 'HaveMax')).set_index(['Name', 'Date'])
```

Suppose I want to set the value of `Dollars` where `Date == '20210102`?  I have found:

```py
df.groupby('Date').indices.get('20210102')  # << Gets array of the rows
df.iloc[df.groupby('Date').indices.get('20210102')]  # << Gets the rows
```

But `df.iloc[df.groupby('Date').indices.get('20210101')]['Dollars'] = 3` gives the `SettingWithCopyWarning`.

What I think would accomplish my goal would be a code sample that sets each Name's `Dollars` on `'20210102'` to, say, double each Name's `Dollars` on `'20210101'`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```
df.loc[df.index.get_level_values('Date') == '20210101', 'Dollars'] = 3
```

Outptut

```
df
               Dollars  HaveMax
Name Date
A    20210101    3.000    False
B    20210101    3.000    False
C    20210101    3.000     True
A    20210102    0.000    False
B    20210102    0.000    False
C    20210102    0.000    False
```

To assign to the previous Date's values:

`df.loc[df.index.get_level_values('Date') == '20210102', 'Dollars'] = df.iloc[df.groupby('Date').indices.get('20210101')].Dollars.values`

Comment: Ah ha!  Using the first expression, and your observation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66179992/2662901) that it is necessary to take `.values` from a series, I was able get an expression for the assignment to the previous day's Dollars – just added to this answer.  But this looks kludgy as hell so I'm wondering if there's a more graceful way....